# MySQL Select All not selected(added) tags for a post using joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To select(query) all selected(added) tag I will use the code :

```
SELECT `tags`.`name`
FROM `post_tag` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `post_tag`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
WHERE `post_tag`.`post_id` = '12'
```

How to query all the tags that are not added to a post using joins

## posts

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | post 1 |
| 2 | post 2 |

## tags

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag 1 |
| 2 | tag 2 |

## post_tag

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |

Comment: I'm lost.  Why do you have `tag_id` values that are not in the `tags` table?

Comment: it is just for sample. I am new to stack overflow Markdown editor. I am now learning how to write a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understand your question is: given a Post ID (e.g. 2), return all the tags that have not been associated with that particular Post Id. So in your example **Tag 1** should be returned as it's not one of those associated with **Post 2**

If my interpretation is correct and you only want to use `join` you can use the following:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM tags AS t LEFT JOIN post_tag AS pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE pt.tag_id IS NULL OR pt.post_id != 2
GROUP BY pt.tag_id;
```

What this query does is to take from the `post_tag` all tags that are either NULL (they are not joined with any existing post) or are joined with all posts except the one you're analysing (in your example, 2). The `group by` is to avoid duplicates.

Another more readable and efficient solution is to use a `subquery`

```
SELECT name FROM tags WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT tag_id FROM post_tag WHERE post_id = 2
);
```

Comment: suppose if I has 5000 tags that are not related to a post. which one is efficient

Comment: The subquery for sure. The Join would need to evaluate all the other post/tag relationship.

Comment: what can I use IN or Joins to get all tags for a post.  

SELECT `terms`.`name`,`terms`.`slug` FROM `post_term` LEFT JOIN `terms` ON `post_term`.`term_id` = `terms`.`id` WHERE `post_term`.`post_id` = '2';
    

  
SELECT name FROM tags WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tag_id FROM post_tag WHERE post_id = 2
);

Answer (score 0):

> How to query all the tags that are not added to a post?

If this is your question, the approach is to generate all post/tag combinations and then remove the ones that exist:

```
select p.*, t.*
from posts p cross join
     tags t
     post_tags pt
     on pt.post_id = p.id and pt.tag_id = t.id
where pt.post_id is null;   -- there is no match
```

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @RaghavendraKJ . . . This doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Suppose if I want all tags that are not related to post id = 2. where can i use the post id in your SQL

Comment: @RaghavendraKJ . . . Then you would have a different question.  I quote the question in this answer.  A different question should be asked as a *new* question.